# Dynamically switching connect in Modelica in simulation

Tags: openmodelica

I have a principal model that involves a lot of components and I want some connections to change when the pressure value changes.
For example

```
if Pressure<1  then connect (evap.a,fad.b) else connect (evap.a,gol.c)
```

Can anyone here help me please, I already tried using `if` and `when` and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible if Pressure is a variable, only if is a parameter or constant. All the connect equations need to be known at *compile time*.

Comment: so there is not any way to achive this idea of port changing during simulation even in dymola???

Comment: That is true. There are some ways to have "variable structure" systems but they are really restricted and they are using state machines to define the modes of the system.

Comment: where can i find an exempl of such systems ,because i really needthis option of port changing during simulation in my work,thank you

Comment: Se more here: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-91908-9_16